# MarkLogic Performance on Windws vs Linux

Tags: linux, windows, performance, marklogic

For our project, we are setting up MarkLogic cluster on Azure.

Is there any major performance difference when it comes to Windows or Linux ?

It would be great if there are any reference links for the same

I have done installation and configuration on both, in real terms it does not matter while setting up.

So want to know from performance perspective, does it really matters?

Workload

- Current size >15M XML files which needs to be loaded into MarkLogic
- Weekly 18K xml files will be ingested

Comment: @jww There are 0 questions tagged MarkLogic on SuperUser, so that's is a tough sell. Most of the relatively small ML dev community isn't on SU.

Comment: @wst - Given ML is a database technology, my guess is [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask for this particular question. But it is just a guess. I try to avoid telling folks where to go. I try to limit advice to telling folks what Stack Overflow is for, and why the question does not fit here.

Comment: @jww There are at least some MarkLogic questions on DBA SE, but they're all very old. I think unless mods are able to move questions to the appropriate SE site, this will be a chicken/egg problem, and everyone will post on SO because all the ML questions are here and so are the devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. There are some minor performance differences, but it depends on your specific workload. For those edge cases, my understanding is that Linux will typically edge out Windows. But focusing on application design best practices and query optimization is significantly more important than the host OS.

Comment: Thanks  wst for rapid reply. I have added workflow info in my original request.

Comment: @ManishJoisar That seems pretty normal for a Marklogic cluster. But by workload I mean specifics of queries and indexes, in addition to data. Most of the time there will be no difference or only a minor difference. If you have a question about expected performance of a *very specific* workload, contact MarkLogic support.

Comment: Thanks wst for your reply. Ok, my bad, Indexes will be say around 6-8 nodes, and in future around 20 nodes, On query side, it will be And/Or and few filters. So when you say edge out windows, it will be kind of 1:1.25 or 1:1.50 Or more ?

Comment: @ManishJoisar Less. And for your workload I suspect you will find no difference.

Comment: Your workload quoted is microscopic, you could run on a era 2000 laptop in RAM. If you need that many nodes my opinion is to consider the infrastructure efficiency of provisioning and  managing 20 windows servers vs 20 linux servers with associated cloud storage/networking -- that outweighs OS differences by far.